# Devise sign in and sign up submit button disabled when accessing through navbar link rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, sign

The sign-up button and sign in button of my devise form is disabled when I try to access both forms via the navbar links. To work I need to refresh the form. Any help ? Thanks in advance

```
<div class="panel panel-default form-signin col-md-offset-2">

<div class="panel-heading">
<h2 class="panel-title">Sign in</h2>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<%= simple_form_for(resource, defaults: { input_html: { class: 'form-control' } }, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

<%= f.input :email %>
<%= f.input :password %>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
 <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %>
  <% end -%>
  </div>


<div class="panel-footer">
<%= f.submit 'Sign in' %> 
<% end %>
</div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-offset-2">
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say disabled do you mean you can no longer access the path?

Comment: I mean that it's impossible to submit the form after entering data or without anything

Comment: @JoelL I found the problem :

Comment: <div class="form-inputs panel-body">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, input_html: { class: 'form-control'} %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, input_html: { class: 'form-control'} %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true, input_html: { class: 'form-control'} %>
  </div>